# Why does shallowReactive not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am new to vue3 and have some confusion about shallowReactive.

**only root-level properties are reactive for a shallow reactive object.**

But when I click the add button, the value of count2 will still change:

```
<script setup>
import { shallowReactive } from 'vue'

const test = shallowReactive({
  count1: 0,
  nested: {
    count2: 0
  }
})
const add = () => {
  test.count1++
  test.nested.count2++
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="add">+</button>
  <div>{{ test.count1 }}</div>
  <div>{{ test.nested.count2 }}</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you modify something nested inside a `shallowReactive` **it doesn't mean the mutation is not performed**. It only means Vue is not told: you need to check for differences between M (model) and V (view/template/DOM) ***now***.

Because you're also changing `test.count1` in the same function, which is watched, the component gets *diff*-ed. The diff-ing doesn't care what's reactive. It only looks for differences between M and V. If it finds any, it updates them.

Let's make separate functions for nested and non-nested props. As you can see, V only updates when the non-nested prop is changed. At that point, the entire view (template) is checked and updated according to model:

```js
const { createApp, shallowReactive } = Vue;

createApp({
  setup() {
    const test = shallowReactive({
      count1: 0,
      nested: {
        count2: 0
      }
    })
    const add = () => {
      test.count1++
    }
    const addWithoutUpdate = () => {
      test.nested.count2++;
    }
    return { test, add, addWithoutUpdate }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.37/vue.global.prod.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="add">+</button>
  <button @click="addWithoutUpdate">Only add to nested</button>
  <div>{{ test.count1 }}</div>
  <div>{{ test.nested.count2 }}</div>
</div>
```

---

In other words, `shallowReactive` doesn't freeze the nested objects. They can be mutated. But Vue will only *diff* the template when something it actually watches changes. Could be the top level of this shallow reference or some other, completely unrelated reactive variable.